# What are the drawbacks to using a rounded background image as opposed border-radius?

Tags: rounded-corners, css

Unfortunately, I have to use IE 8 & 9 for our application.

My people want a rounded corner box.

OPTION 1 :  Use border-radius and 'edge'.  We will get rounded for people with 9 but not 8....

OPTION 2 : Just go with a rounded image like we have for years, this will look the same in both browsers...

Here's my question - are there any drawbacks to using OPTION 2 BESIDES the loading time for the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one zooms into the page, the rounded image will look pixelated. If you want to, you can use [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com) for rounded borders in IE8, however [html5please](http://html5please.com/#border-radius) recommends against.